# NFS: mount.nfs: Protocol not supported

Tags: mount, nfs, fstab

I want to mount the NFS share of a Zyxel NSA310s NAS. Showmount, called on the client machine, shows the share:

```
$ showmount 10.0.0.100 -e
Export list for 10.0.0.100:
/i-data/7fd943bf/nfs/zyxelNFS *
```

The client's /etc/fstab contains the line:

```
10.0.0.100:/i-data/7fd943bf/nfs/zyxelNFS /media/nasNFS nfs rw  0 0
```

But mounting does not work:

```
sudo mount /media/nasNFS/ -v
mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon May 25 17:34:46 2015
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=10.0.0.100,clientaddr=10.0.0.2'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=10.0.0.100'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 10.0.0.100 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Program/version mismatch
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 10.0.0.100 prog 100003 vers 3 prot UDP port 2049
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Program/version mismatch
mount.nfs: Protocol not supported
```

`nfs-common` is installed. What else can be missing?

Comment: What version of the NFS protocol is provided by the NSA310s? It looks like your client only supports version 3 and maybe the server is only version 4 (or 2)

Comment: I don't know the NFS version that the NSA310s uses internally. The client runs a current Ubuntu 15.04 distribution, is it necessary to explicitly allow NFS v4 ?

Comment: try `nfs4` in the `/etc/fstab` instead of `nfs`. I looked up the specs for the NSA310s but doesn't specify which version of NFS is supported.

Comment: with nfs4 in the /etc/fstab I get 
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Mon May 25 19:13:48 2015

mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 
'addr=10.0.0.100,clientaddr=10.0.0.2'

mount.nfs4: mount(2): Protocol not supported

mount.nfs4: Protocol not supported

Comment: I have not other suggestions that you could try, sorry.

Comment: what does `rpcinfo 10.0.0.100` tell you? It should mention the supported versions. It looks like the NFS server does not like UDP. You can force TCP using the mount option `tcp` but it will probably does not help you directly since TCP is already tried according to line 7 in your output. Is there a firewall in between which is blocking the mount to succeed? And sometimes mounts will succeed by just restarting the NFS server.

Comment: rpcinfo, just the two lines with nfs:
   100003    2    udp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        unknown
    100003    2    tcp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        unknown
There is no firewall between.

Comment: In that case your NFS server only supports version 2. Try to mount using option `vers=2`

Comment: Lambert, you had the right answer. After hours of searching it finally works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 40):

To summarize the steps taken to get to the answer:

According to the output given the NFS server does not like NFSv4 nor UDP. To see the capabilities of the NFS server you can use `rpcinfo 10.0.0.100` (you might extend the command to filter for `nfs` by: `|egrep "service|nfs"`)

Apparently the only version supported by the server is version 2:

```
rpcinfo 10.0.0.100 |egrep "service|nfs"
program version netid     address                service    owner
100003  2       udp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        unknown
100003  2       tcp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        unknown
```

Solution to mount the export is to use mount option `vers=2` either on the commandline:

```
mount -o rw,vers=2 10.0.0.100:/i-data/7fd943bf/nfs/zyxelNFS /media/nasNFS
```

or by editing the /etc/fstab:

```
10.0.0.100:/i-data/7fd943bf/nfs/zyxelNFS /media/nasNFS nfs rw,vers=2  0 0
```

Another approach may be to change the NFS server to support version 3 (or even 4).

Comment: Useful pointer to rpcinfo for troubleshooting, thanks,

Answer (score 11):

I'm getting this error on Fedora 31.  It turns out the drive is already mounted...

Comment: What, "Protocol not supported"? Are you sure it's because the drive is already mounted? I don't get that error when repeating an NFS mount request for a share that's already mounted. (In fact, I don't get any error at all.) I only get the error when there's a protocol mismatch

Comment: Yep, I dismounted.  Remounted and no error.  Then remounted again while mounted and again got the error.  I have other projects so I can't look into it now but I thought I'd throw this cause up as it apparently happens under some conditions even I have no idea why and agree it doesn't make sense.

Comment: can confirm, same error happened to me. nfs3 share mounted on ubuntu2204, newest nfs-common pkg. exported from synology nas

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the "Protocol not supported" error as well. In my case the root cause turned out to be a subtle issue with a DNS reverse entry.

Background: I was using NFSv4 and had the following entries in `/etc/exports`:

```
/srv/nfs      *.example.com(ro,fsid=root,insecure,no_subtree_check,async,root_squash)
/srv/nfs/data myhost.example.com(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

Instead of the FQDN, running `host 1.2.3.4` returned pointers to both "myhost." and "myhost.example.com.". My NFS server seemed to look at the first PTR entry in the DNS response only which didn't match the wildcard in `/etc/exports` and as a consequence it blocked NFSv4 from this host. So if you use rules based on host names in `/etc/exports` double-check that DNS reverse lookups work correctly for your clients.

Answer (score 1):

```
[root@sousvide mnt]# mount projects/
mount.nfs: Protocol not supported
```

The solution to this error in my case was adjusting the Freenas (BSD) settings "Authorized Hosts and IP Addresses" to allow the target machine in question access...

/etc/fstab had an entry like

```
x.x.x.x:/mnt/media/projects /mnt/projects nfs defaults,timeo=900,retrans=5,_netdev,noauto 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

So I was getting that same error (protocol not supported) although my issue was a result of the NFS server not allowing my IP to mount (hbac rules). Had to login to the NFS Server and allow my IP.

When attempting to mount with -vvv, I saw various denied prior to the final "protocol not supported" that appeared without running the verbose options. .

Answer (score -5):

try to use this option

```
....   nfs    rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr 0 0
```

Comment: please explain why

Comment: In some cases these parameters can help improving performance but they aren't related to the connection issues the OP described.